# embed video in html?

Tags: asp-classic, video-streaming

I want to embed a video in an asp page. I am using this code

```
<embed autoplay="false" controller="true" loop="false" name="JF Video" 
pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" 
src="https://www.anylink.com/english/video/videoname.mp4" height="250" border="1" width="320">
```

problem is that autoplay=false is not working as is starts playing automatically as page loads and this video is not getting played in firefox ? I have wasted more than 5 hours in it.

What is the solution of this problem and if there is any other better way to play video in asp web page [no html5 tag], please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `object` tag and replace your code with this.

```
<object name="Video" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" standby="Loading Quicktime components..." width="400" height="200" > <param name="src" value="https://www.anylink.com/english/video/videoname.mp4"></param> <param name="autoplay" value="false"></param> <param name="controller" value="true"></param> <param name="enablejavascript" value="true"></param> <param name="playCount" value="1"></param> <param name="starttime" value="0"></param> <embed name="Video" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" type="video/quicktime" src="https://www.anylink.com/english/video/videoname.mp4" autoplay="false" controller="true" enablejavascript="true" starttime="0" width="400" height="200"></embed> </object>
```

Comment: can you tell me how you generated this classid ?

Comment: @WinWorld, That's not really important. I found that from a link. By the way did it work for you ?